# Computing the cross ratio

Tags: python, python-2.7, math, sage

I want to write a function in python to compute the cross ratio of four projective points, and I am wondering whether there is an elegant and succinct implementation to handle infinite cases.

A naive implementation of the cross ratio looks like this:

```
ratio = lambda a,b,c: (a-c)/(b-c)
cross_ratio = lambda a,b,c,d: ratio(a,b,c)/ratio(a,b,d)
```

But this fails when one of the inputs is Infinity. This should not happen, but rather we would like the infinities to "cancel out each other" and give us a simple ratio.

For example, the cross ratio of `Infinity, 0, 1, -1` should be `-1`.

Also, I would like to handle points expressed as a ratio of two numbers. Thus `(1 1)`would be the number `1`, while `(1,0)`would represent `Infinity`, etc.

I could always fall back to a definition by cases and make do with it, but I feel this may be a good opportunity to learn good design.

I am using Python 2.7 and the Sagemath module. Any advices on how to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try this:

```
def det2(a, b): return a[0]*b[1] - a[1]*b[0]
def cr2(a, b, c, d): return vector([det2(a,c)*det2(b,d), det2(a,d)*det2(b,c)])
```

This would use homogeneous coordinates on input, so you'd inout two-element vectors. It would also return its result in homogeneous coordinates, as a two-element vector, so you could get a clean description of infinite cross ratio. If you need the result as an element of some field instead, just use division instead of the vector constructor:

```
def cr2(a, b, c, d): return (det2(a,c)*det2(b,d))/(det2(a,d)*det2(b,c))
```

I added the suffix `2` to my formulas because personally I often need the cross ratio of four collinear points in the plane. In that case, I'd use

```
def det3(a, b, c):
  return matrix([a,b,c]).det() # Or spell this out, if you prefer
def cr3(a, b, c, d, x):
  return vector([det3(a,c,x)*det3(b,d,x), det3(a,d,x)* det3(b,c,x)])
```

Now let `x` be any point *not* collinear with `a,b,c,d` and you get the cross ratio of these four points. Or more generally, if `a,b,c,d` are not collinear, you get the cross ratio of the four lines connecting these to `x`, which can be useful for a number of scenarios, many of them involving conics.

Answer (score 1):

The best is to work with the projective line.

The documentation here contains useful hints:
http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/schemes/sage/schemes/projective/projective_space.html

Here is an implementation of the cross-ratio, with examples.

```
sage: P = ProjectiveSpace(1, QQ)
sage: oo, zero, one = P(1, 0), P(0, 1), P(1, 1)
sage: tm = P.point_transformation_matrix
sage: def cross_ratio(a, b, c, d):
....:     a, b, c, d = P(a), P(b), P(c), P(d)
....:     m = tm([a, b, c], [oo, zero, one])
....:     return P(list(m*vector(list(d))))
....: 
sage: cross_ratio(oo, zero, one, 1/2)
(1/2 : 1)
sage: cross_ratio(1, 2, 3, 4)
(4/3 : 1)
```